# Merging two images in to one in pygame

Tags: python, pygame

I have a program that takes two different images - one a tile texture (32x32) that has no blank/transparent spots and the second one is an effect (cracks effect) that has transparent pixels and it is also 32x32 .
From those two images i want to make one.

I tried placing the second image on the first one but it did not work (i thing i don't let the transparency work in it)

First of all - how do i get the transparency to work on an image in pygame(any color key) and different opacity's.
and Second thing is - How do i merge them?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To "merge" two images, just blit the second one onto the first one.

Given these two images (`1.png`, `2.png`)

[image: 1.png]
[image: 2.png]

here's an example:

```
import pygame

pygame.init()
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((200, 50))

image = pygame.image.load("1.png")
shadow = pygame.image.load("2.png")

merged = image.copy()
merged.blit(shadow, (0, 0))

while True:  
    screen.fill(pygame.color.Color('white'))
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            raise

    screen.blit(image, (0,  0))                
    screen.blit(shadow, (50, 0))
    screen.blit(image, (100, 0))
    screen.blit(shadow, (100, 0))
    screen.blit(merged, (150, 0))
    pygame.display.flip()
```

Result:

[image]

If that does not work for you, your surfaces may have different pixel formats. Fix that by calling [`convert_alpha`](http://pygame.org/docs/ref/surface.html#pygame.Surface.convert_alpha) on each surface.

If your problem is about mixing surfaces with a color key and surfaces with per-pixel transparency, take a look at this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11649145/142637).